# UI Dropdown Performance Issue with large Select Dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, semantic-ui

I'm working with Semantic UI dropdowns, and I need to create a dropdown with around 3000 options in it.  The dropdown works very well, except for one case.  If the user clears out the search text, the dropdown completely locks up.  I believe it's because it's trying to reload all the elements.

I've looked through the settings (http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/settings) that are available for the dropdown, but nothing stands out in change the way it handles reloading all the elements.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

HTML:

```
<div class="ui fluid search selection dropdown">
                    <input type="hidden" name="security_group"></input>
                    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                    <div class="default text">Select Security Group</div>
                    <div class="menu">
                        <j:while test="${reference.next()}">
                            <div class="item" data-value="${reference.sys_id}">${reference.u_name}</div>
                        </j:while>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
              $(".ui.fluid.search.selection.dropdown").dropdown();
              $(".ui.fluid.search.selection.dropdown").width("100%");
        });
```

Comment: Hi @ChrisRiv have you caught any solution for this?